# Exclude certain classes from class cache

Tags: symfony, caching, typo3

i am trying to build a sf2 connector for [typo3](http://typo3.org/).
Problem is that both are using `Psr/Logger/Interface` and both keep them in different folders.

While typo has the path of `Psr` tightly bound in the Core (**sigh**), symfony2 has it defined directly in the class cache, which i do not want to deactivate for performance reasons.

So the Questions are:

- *Either*: How can i prevent Symfony2 from using certain classes in it's class cache?
- *Or*: How can i wrap all class definitions in symfony2 class cache with a `if (!class_exists('\Namespace\of\that\class\ThatClass')) { ...` ?

**Update:**
So far i solved it by excluding classes from the symfony classmap that use LoggerInterface.

I do this by overwriting the doLoadClassCache method in my AppKernel.
This however is more of a Workarround i think:

```
protected function doLoadClassCache($name, $extension)
{
    if (!$this->booted && is_file($this->getCacheDir().'/classes.map')) {
        $classes = array_filter(include($this->getCacheDir().'/classes.map'), function($item) {
            return (strpos($item, 'Monolog') === false);
        });
        ClassCollectionLoader::load($classes, $this->getCacheDir(), $name, $this->debug, false, $extension);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does really fail? Normally, the autoloaders should stack, thus the class should be loaded by the first autoloader and no more.

Comment: Did you try this with TYPO3 7.2 (master) and composer?

Comment: No, it was Typo 6.10.* i think.